# How to obtain non-flattened PDF output of a signed (template derived) envelope?

Tags: docusignapi

We need to be able to read back the data of the form fields after the document is signed, however the document given to us by the docusign API is flattened and the form fields and their data has become "baked into" the PDF file and our tools cannot identify the data in such a state.  The data needs to remain as form fields.  Only the template derived envelopes seem to do this.

If a PDF document with its form fields intact is uploaded during the envelope creation process, instead of using a template, then the resultant signed document still has the form fields intact and our tools can extract the data.  We need this behavior for template derived envelopes, or otherwise obtain the form fields and their data.

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is achievable but not using the pdf. Instead you can use custom fields and/or tags and use the API to read the information from the envelope. If the information was provided by the users during signing it's probably in the tags and if it was provided by a third party system or coming from the original document - it can be stored in custom fields. This is what we call merge-fields and how our CRM integrations work.

Comment: Thanks!, this had me looking around for the tabs, and this turned out to contain all of the imported fields, and the "tabs", the fields and data the user fills in:

`{{baseUrl}}/envelopes/{{envelopeId}}/recipients/{{recipientId}}/tabs`


We just need to make that API call whenever importing the signed document back into our system, for strategies like this.